# Cross-compile OPUS codec for blackfin

Tags: windows, makefile, opus, blackfin

I have succesfully worked with it on linux setting up a stream between 2 linux pc's. That is straigt forward following the README file for OPUS.

Now I need to cross-compile the OPUS-codec for a Blackfin ADSP-BF707 on windows. I have tried to compile though CrossCore Embedded Studio, but then i do not have all the includes and defines that the make file is setting up.

I can see that a define can be set for a ARM processor but i have not found anything for Blackfin. Their Q&A tells that the codec has been compiled the the Blackfin. In linux the "./configure"-command builds the makefile but i do not see how this is done for a cross-compilation. Do i build my own makefile or what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The OPUS codec for Blackfin includes a (closed source) library from Analog Devices with some optimizations in the signal processing part. The current version (CELT Codec for Blackfin Production Code (Rev. 1.2.0)) is based on the reference OPUS codec version 0.9.8

My suggestion is that you get the reference version 0.9.8 from the Xiph.org directly and compile it. In my company, we already did an investigation whether the OPUS codec from Analog Devices produces the 100% byte identical result as the reference implementation and the answer is: yes.